# Python - EOFError: Ran out of input

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing

I want to run parallel processing, using the class but the code gives this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\MonPc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\Users\MonPc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 115, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

This is just similar to the original code that I want to work on.
MyCode :

```
from multiprocessing import Process

class class1:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        txt = "Rachid"
        p1 = class2(txt)
        p1.start()
        p1.join()

class class2(Process):
    def __init__(self, txt):
        Process.__init__(self)
        self.txt = txt

    def run (self):
        print("*"*10)
        print(self.txt)
        print("*"*10)

class1()
```

How can I avoid getting this error ?

Comment: Cannot reproduce the error.  This code runs as expected.

Comment: Confirmed, cannot reproduce. I do get a different error: `RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.` This is solved by putting the instantiation of `class1` into a `if __name__ == '__main__:` block. With this change I get the expected output.

Comment: Maybe this error is specific to Windows environment. I'm running MacOS.

Comment: @MichaelRuth Yes this gives good results, but `Class1()` is called for in another class, It can not be put in  `if __name__ == '__main__:`